# Visual Studio 2010, VisualHg, keeps adding bin, obj folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore, visualhg

Everything was working fine for 3 months, now suddenly when I open Visual Studio, it adds all untracked files in the root solution folder to Hg, i.e. bin and obj folders included.

Steps:

1. Close VS2010
2. Use Tortoise Hg workbench to forget files added by VS2010 when it opened
3. Open VS2010, all the files start being added back into Hg, it appears to happen when the "Preparing solution" dialog appears

I edited the .hgignore file in the root folder to include "bin" and "obj", but that is being ignored by VS.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try editting your ignore file to include the following instead :

```
[Bb]in/
[Dd]ebug*/
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
```

Sometimes the capitalization can change (I can't remember exactly what causes it..)

Comment: I never got a chance to try this. The issue stopped happening, I have no idea why. I changed the source control from Hg to None and back more than a few times. I also repeatedly told VisualHg and TortoiseHg to forget the files that kept getting added. Now it appears to be working as expected.